# How do I get the Default Content module to work?

Tags: 7

I saw the [Default Content](http://drupal.org/project/defaultcontent) module. I wanted to know the real purpose of this module, how do we exactly use it, and what the difference with the node_export module is.

Comment: Hi you need to rethink your question, you say you want to use it because you saw the description but then state you don't know the purpose of it. If you don't know the purpose of it then why do you want to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use default content to give your nodes a machine name (as seen when editing a node).  Then you can use features module to export those nodes to a feature.

Comment: How is this module different from node export module?

Answer (score 2):

You don't *use* it as such, rather it provides extra options to the Features module:

> When the module is installed nodes get optional "machine name" field. Nodes with filled-out machine names automatically become exportable from the Features interface.

Comment: How is this module different from node export module?

Comment: @Hacker The difference is that with the Default Content module, you export the nodes as a feature.